# How to remove Import Error occured after installation of tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi, importerror

I am doing a project for traffic signal automation on a virtual machine. It needs to detect cars using image detection process.
Code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox
im = cv2.imread('cars_4.jpeg')
bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(im)
output_image = draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)
plt.imshow(output_image)
plt.show()
print('Number of cars in the image is '+ str(label.count('car')))
```

Operating system: Debian Buster with Raspberry Pi Desktop
https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/

Kernel version : 4.19

Python Version: 3.7.3

Pip Version:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 21.1.1 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Libraries used:

-Open cv

- cvlib
- matplotlib.

After installing cvlib it requires me to install tensor flow, after installation of tensorflow at the time of execution this error occurs:

Error :

```
(venv) pi@raspberry:~/Desktop/TSA $ python3 main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cvlib as cv
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/TSA/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvlib/_init_.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .gender_detection import detect_gender
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/TSA/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cvlib/gender_detection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_file
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/TSA/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/_init_.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/TSA/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_init_.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/TSA/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/TSA/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/pi/Desktop/TSA/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Tried adding
"export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64/"
in .bashrc file, still same error.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but perhaps try uninstalling tensorflow the same way you installed it and then running `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`

It's also worth noting that your pip warning message mentions python 3.7, and I see you're running your code with `python3`. Is it possible some of your libraries are installed for python 2.7.16 when they need to instead be installed for python 3.7?

Comment: If you are working on a Raspberry Pi, be specific with how you have installed tensorflow and which version into, the details of Raspbery Pi board, details of the OS, Python version, because you said Python Version: 2.7.16 but it is apparently 3.7 as ( /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)) in your post.

Comment: I have edited my post, it was 3.7 version of python. I've already mentioned I'm working virtually on Raspberry pi, not an actual Raspberry pi device & I've also put the link for Desktop OS I'm using. Reinstalled tensorflow using given command, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on error it seems like something is wrong with your installation of cvlib.

I guess you can try again:

```
pip install opencv-python tensorflow

pip install cvlib
```

And see if that yields some error message that might direct to you what could be wrong.

As mentioned in the comment by @swarles-barkley maybe your environment requires the above to actually be:

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python tensorflow

python3 -m pip install cvlib
```

**EDIT** (after a comment):
Again something is definitely odd with your env setup. You can try to uninstall and then reinstall tensorflow and cvlib and while doing so closely look for any warnings coming out from compile process.
This [discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34991) might give you some ideas on how to debug the issue.

Comment: I've used these commands but it is still giving me the same error. @draganstankovic

Comment: I have used new environment and installed everything but it is still showing the error. From the discussion, I couldn't find "venv/lib/python3.7.3/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so"  directory in my project, my directory listing : https://dpaste.org/tfQa